# Why do I keep getting % at the end of my script

Tags: bash

I've been making a couple of scripts and it seems that I keep getting `%` sign at the end of executing them.

Examples of one of those scripts:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep -v '^#' | rev | cut -d ':' -f 7 | sort -r |\
awk '{if(NR >= '1' && NR <= '50')print $0}' | paste -sd ',' - |\
sed 's/,/, /g' | sed 's/[^.]$/&./' | tr -d "\n"
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image: screenshot of the result]

I searched around but I found no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove all the newlines at the end, so there are no newlines in the output. Including the one right before your prompt.

```
cat ... | tr -d "\n" ; echo
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no newline character at the end of line and shell is adding one to put prompt on new line.